# Using SPDY large value stalled/bloccking in chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, timeline, spdy

Why when using SPDY connection to the server Google Chrome timeline indicates a **huge** part of the request being spent ***stalled/blocking***?

I thought that it was possible for multiple requests to be processed over a single SPDY connection, and time ***stalled*** should be much, much less as a result: connection time should be practically zero.

[image: SCREEN1]

Comment: Are you using a proxy along the way somewhere? Looks like everything has a little stalled time, which could indicate proxy negotiation.

Comment: I don't use a proxy along the way